# del key on a PC keyboard with MAC mini

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard

Windows guy all my life, I am checking out a mac mini. So far so good.
I was able to map HOME/END keys as I wanted under XCode. 
There is one thing I am not able to figure out. TO the right of the keyboard, there is this "del/[period]" key. I use it to do a forward delete. I am not able to map that. If I could toggle the numlock, I can possibly use the del key for forward delete. 
Yes I did search the net for a few days and could not find an answer.
I would be grateful if someone can point me to a possible solution to this.
Yes I already know that there is a separate "DELETE" key in the middle, but I am more used to the "del/[period]" key in the numlock region.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That depends upon the terminal emulator (and for X) the keyboard configuration.  There is no one solution which will fit all cases.

For the default terminal in OSX (Terminal.app), you can add/modify definitions of special keys in its *Preferences* (*Keyboard*) dialog.  A "forward delete" is one of the known special keys.